# How can I maximize an absorbing state outcome in a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process

I am working on Markov Chain for a computer science project. The problem is based on the gunshot in "The Good The Bad and the Ugly". Three shooters have a certain chance to hit their target and a certain chance to choose one of the other two shooters. So the Good has a chance *g* to hit his target, The Bad has a chance *b* and The Ugly a chance *u*.

I want to show that each shooter should target the best gunslinger when they shoot to maximize their likelihood to survive. For this I introduce *gu*, the probability for G to choose U, *bu* the probability for B to choose U and *ub* the probability for U to choose B.

I've built my Markov chain, I implemented my transition matrix, identified the fundamental matrix F and the Absorbtion matrix A. So I just have to look at the first column of A to know that to go from the initial state (GBU *everyone is alive and G starts shooting*) to the absorbing states G,B,U I have a probability of respectively A11, A21 and A31.

So my question is, how can I find a way to maximize those last three probabilities. I've considered setting *g*, *b* and *u* and find optimal values of *gu*, *bu* and *ub* but I don't see how I could do that. Should I consider A as a function of *gu*, *bu* and *ub* and find the critical points such that `∇A=0` ? But considering that A is a very long expression it seems very unpractical.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXR6f.jpg (The Markov chain and the transition matrix).

Thanks in advance for your help.

*Small update: the question accepted answered in a mathematical point of view to the question, however I am still looking for an approach using Markov chain and the absorbing matrix! So feel free to comment!*

Comment: Aha, I need to understand this one carefully! If I am thinking correctly, this one looks like it could fall under stochastic dominance-based techniques, and hence be solved in a simpler way than requiring A explicitly. Great question, +1. I have just one small doubt : so let's say U chooses G,and U misses. Then G gets to be the next shooter, right? (I'm just understanding the Markov chain here). Also, I'm not sure that this is a Markov chain , because if one shooter dies then the two remaining shooters can only shoot each other : so this chain is not time-homogenous.

Comment: This is a Markov chain. Its a tricky one but it is a Markov chain ;) G is the first shooter, B is the second and U the third. The first state is GBU because all of them are alive and G shoots. If he misses we arrive in the stage BUG because B shoots, and if he misses we are in state UGB. If one shooter dies they either shoot at each other forever or ultimately hit the other. The absorbing states are G,B and U because only one remain, so only the winner survive and I want to determine how do they have to shoot (probabilities) to maximize their chance of winning.

Comment: Thank you, I see that my model was wrong it is indeed a Markov chain. In that case, I might try the stochastic dominance argument when I have the time.

Comment: Hey there, you got the time to check?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for reminding me. I took a good look at this question before my profession called me! It looks like I might have to place this in a rigorous mathematical setting before I can proceed (I believe that calling it a "Markov chain" is slightly undergeneralizing what is occurring here). Thankfully, I believe that I can do that, but (because I'd rather be comprehensive than just outline the details) I will need some time, which I hope you will grant me. In return, I promise to answer your question to the best of my abilities.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I tried pretty hard but the numbers have gotten too difficult. I have values and the inverses and what not, but solving the equations couldn't be avoided and after some point silly mistakes crept in and , yeah, things gone wrong. Nice question, though. In return, I think I'll probably bounty it.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway for your time! I think I could also use the 6 variables of the problem, and calculate the critical point of the Absorbing states coefficient I need. One problem: calculation of the F matrix is way to long since I'm in dimension 9. SO not very practical...

Comment: Hi Chris, I think I had the same problem as you, but I had the following insight. One may not need to compute the F matrix, if one can figure out some structure that it has, which leads to the solution of some equation involving it having that structure. The point is that your "extreme" value is attained when the parameters themselves attain extreme values. Such a situation can often result from structural constraints on $F$ such as convexity of some set or function, and that's what I tried to express in the bounty text.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the goal is to prove that when the shooter choses the one that has the greatest chance to land his shot, he maximizes his chances to survive. So if we have g<b<u the probabilities to land a shot for G,B and U, then U will shoot at B and G & B will always shoot at U.  It means that we should have a maximization for a tuple (1,1,1) in that configuration-(gu,bu,ub) the chances G has to shoot at U, B at U and U at B. My main problem is the representation of that function you're talking about because we're in 4d if you set the shooting probabilies (1d for the proba)

Comment: Hi, I agree. We need to represent that function in a way such that, without really getting it explicitly, we can still show that it's maximized at $(1,1,1)$. That is the challenge here : I'm pretty sure that it's *not* to get the function explicitly, and even so it would still be a hard question. One approach of mine has already failed.

Comment: What if we set the probabilities in such way x<y<z are the g,b and u. And we check all combinations to form a set of values (randomly generated and then sorted in cases). Then we could set lets say gu and bu and see the variation of the probabilities for the one left over variables. Maybe checking the maximum for each combination and then the 3 variations of gu, bu and ub individually we could recombine everything to see when we have a a maximum for everyone at the same time. A graphical way to see the gradient one by one to see when we have critical points.

Comment: I tried that, actually. It was quite cumbersome and I couldn't finish it. I'm really sorry that we couldn't get to the bottom of this problem, even with a bounty.

Comment: It's alright I appreciate your help !

Comment: Here is a little update after talking to my teacher. So I suggested to simply look at the bar plot I get after checking all possible cases of gu, bu and ub (and doing an average on randomly generated values of g, b and u). And apparently that's enough. It can work just like that to show that a shooter will have a higher chance to win if for example he follows the correct strategy and the two others don't. That's pretty much it. It's not really mathematical enough for me so it's kinda sad though.

Comment: That's really sad, and not how I thought it would work. This bounty is about to expire, and the only evidence I draw from that is that either this problem is not interesting to others (which shocks me!) or it's really hard (which I'd be very delighted to acknowledge).  It's sad that we're having to conclude from a bar graph, but once I'm out of a busy period, I will really give this problem my best shot. That best shot, however, may not be "levelled down", and I might have to draw from research papers and heavy textbooks, but I so want to get to the bottom of this one.

Comment: That's really thoughtful of you. My deadline is on the 17th of december but it's totally fine if it takes you 3 months to figure it out. I really appreciate your gesture!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do this from the point of view of $G$, but it's easy to see that the same analysis applies to the other two.

The crux is that $G$'s strategy only comes into play in the state GBU, where it only influences the probability of entering state BG or UG depending on if $G$ aims at $U$ or $B$ respectively.

Intuitively, $G$ would prefer to end up in a one-on-one duel with whichever of $U$ and $G$ is worse as shooting, so $G$ should always shoot at the better shot.

To show this formally, we compute the probability of $B$ surviving  from state BG.
This happens if $B$ misses; then either $G$ kills $B$ or $G$ misses and we're back in state BG.
Setting up the relevant equations:
\begin{align*}
\Pr(G\text{ survives} | BG)
&= \Pr(BG \rightarrow GB \rightarrow G) + \Pr(BG \rightarrow GB \rightarrow BG)\Pr(G\text{ survives} | BG) \\
&= (1-b)g + (1-b)(1-g) \Pr(G\text{ survives} | BG), \\
\Pr(G\text{ survives} | BG)
&= \frac{(1-b)g}{1 - (1 - b)(1 - g)} \\
&= \frac{g}{(1-b)^{-1} - (1-g)},
\end{align*}
which is decreasing in $b$.

Similarly, the probability of $G$ surviving from state UG is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(G\text{ survives} | UG)
= \frac{g}{(1-u)^{-1} - (1-g)}.
\end{align*}

You can verify from this that when $b > u$, we have that $\Pr(G\text{ survives} | BG) < \Pr(G\text{ survives} | UG)$ and vice versa if $b < u$.
Therefore, $G$'s probability of survival are maximised by aiming at the better shot.

---

This analysis assumes that $G$ must shoot at either $B$ or $U$.
Somewhat famously, if $G$ is allowed to shoot into the air, they might prefer to do so if they are the worst shot.

This is because the state BUG may preferable to UG or BG for $G$.
If $G$ is worst, while there are $3$ remaining people, $U$ and $B$ will prefer to shoot at each other, and when one of the hits, they system will enter state GU or GB depending on who hits, which $G$ prefers to UG or BG respectively since it's $G$'s turn to shoot.

Comment: I don't really agree with your probability. When we have GB, the probability to go from GB to G is simply g, the chance of G to hit his shot. Same for the transition GU - G.

Comment: Can you point out the particular probability you disagree with? Because I agree with your statement, and used it to compute $\Pr(BG \rightarrow GB \rightarrow G) = (1-b)g$. Perhaps I should make it clear that by $\Pr(G \text{ survives} | BG)$ I meant the probability that G survives in the long-term given that we are in state BG, not just in the next step.

Comment: The thing is that I don't use those probabilities you're describing. I only care about the transition probabilities between each nodes. That's how I build my transition Matrix. The whole point of this project is to use Markov Matrix Algebra. So I am using the absorption matrix to determine the probability to go from GBU to G or B or U

Comment: After reading carefuly your analysis, I realized that it somehow explained a lot. I think I was too focused on the P(G|GB) part as I had a long discussion with my teacher on this, because I was using Markov chain. You actually explained pretty well. I apologize for my stubbornness.